# How to pass client variable to server side function

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below code [Part 1] have one server side function call `GetItemUrl()`.
Here I don't want to use `CableFault` as constant Parameter but parameter value will decide on base of service call . When i am trying to change parameter values as mention in part 2 code , its giving me compile error . Is it because i am trying to pass client side value to server side function ?
If is so please suggest me for solution

Part 1: Working----

```
"CableFault": function () { $result.load("<%= GetItemUrl("CableFault") %>?ajax=1").fadeIn()},
```

Part 2 : Not working---

```
Var ParamValue= ServicecallFromAjax();
"CableFault": function () { $result.load("<%= GetItemUrl(ParamValue) %>?ajax=1").fadeIn() },
```

Comment: "CableFault": function () { $result.load("<%= GetItemUrl(" + ParamValue + ") %>?ajax=1").fadeIn try

Comment: by the time html arrives to the browser, code `<%= GetItemUrl(ParamValue) %>` has had been executed on the server and is not part of the page